# When I run the script below I get an "undefined offset 2" error in php

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $grpm_phno = $_POST['grpm_phno'];
    $grmid = $_POST['groupid'];
    $grpm_name = $_POST['grpm_name'];
    $name = explode(',', "$grpm_name");
    $phone = explode(',', "$grpm_phno");
    $countt = count($name);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $countt; $i++)
    {
        $x = $name[$i];
        $y = $phone[$i];
        $dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

        // Insert Query of SQL

        $query = mysql_query("insert into grp_mst(grpm_name, grpm_phno, grpm_grpcatm_id,grpm_typ,grpm_crtdon) values ('$x', '$y', '$grmid', 'b', '$dt')");
    }
}
```

input given:

```
name:raj,mohan

number:61231,3618372
```

output:

```
raj :61231

mohan:3618372
```

and empty row
any help

Comment: instead of `for` loop try `foreach` loop http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of [tag:php-5.5] and removed in [tag:php-7]. So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @While youre perfectly right that mysql_* is deprecated and should not be used for more then two reasons this isnt a duplicate of that question you linked at all.

Answer (score 3):

Why won't you use `foreach()`(***as it take care of indexes itself***):-

```
foreach($name as $key=>$value){
 $x = $value;
 $y = $phone[$key];
 $dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

 $query = mysql_query("insert into grp_mst(grpm_name, grpm_phno, grpm_grpcatm_id,grpm_typ,grpm_crtdon) values ('$x', '$y', '$grmid', 'b', '$dt')");
}
```

***Important notes:-***

1.`mysql_*` library is deprecated in php-5.5 and removed in php-7. Turn towards `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` along with latest `php 7` version.

2.Always use `prepared statements` of `mysqli_*` or `PDO` library to prevent Your code from `SQL INJECTION`.

***REFERENCE:-***

[php mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[php PDO prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 items in your array, index `2` is the third one (and does not exists given your input)

```
$countt = count($name);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $countt; $i++)
/* => */
for ($i = 0; $i < $countt; $i++)
```

Comment: thanks Oulalahakabu , its working fine

Comment: @jayaram  it's not about working fine and go. Its about upgrading your knowledge and code as well. Please check once my answer and read notes  section carefully

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = explode(',', "$grpm_name");
$phone = explode(',', "$grpm_phno");
```

rewrite it as

```
$name = explode(',', $grpm_name);
$phone = explode(',', $grpm_phno);
```

Comment: it getting
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: when u pass a data in double quotes it act's like a string not as a variable

Answer (score 0):

either use `foreach` loop or modify your `for` loop like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $countt; $i++)
```